# How does Vue introduce the JS module compiled by browserify?

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, browserify

Here is a JS module compiled using browserify: [repo](https://github.com/arscan/encom-globe/tree/master/build)

It can be introduced in the browser through the script tag. After introduction, it will add an object named 'ENCOM' to the global object.

I try to import directly in Vue project through 'import' & 'require'.As a result, npm run serve/build/lint will get stuck. (can be cancelled by Ctrl + C)

This is how I import:

```
/* main.ts */
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import 'boxicons'

// Delete this line and the project can start normally
import './assets/globe/index'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('body')
```

I noticed that [there](https://github.com/arscan/encom-globe/blob/master/browserify.js) is a configuration file of browse, which is as follows:

```
/* browserify.js */
window.ENCOM = (window.ENCOM || {});
window.ENCOM.Globe = require('./src/Globe.js');
```

I tried to change it to this, but I couldn't compile it:

```
const Globe = require('./src/Globe.js')
export default Globe /* report errors */
export { Globe } /* report errors */
export default require('./src/Globe.js') /* report errors */
export { require('./src/Globe.js') } /* report errors */
```

So how can I modify it so that it can become a JS module that can be imported through import?

Comment: You should not be mixing `import`/`export` with `require`. Why aren't you writing `import Globe './src/Globe.js'; export default Globe; export {Globe};`?

Comment: try `require('').default`

Comment: No, I just listed four methods I tried to export as modules (I wrote them together for your convenience)